# How to use CMDR as vs code default integrated terminal

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I want to use CMDR as VS Code default integrated terminal. I have added the following options in my `settings.json`

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "/k %CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\init.bat"
],
```

and it was working but with this new VS Code update `Version: 1.60.0` it stopped working.

any suggestions? how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also had this problem today and managed to fix it by updating `settings.json` as follows:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "Cmder": {
    "path": [
      "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
      "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
    ],
    "args": ["/K", "C:\\Program Files\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"]
  }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Cmder"
```

*Make sure to update the path to cmder to match the install location on your system*

These old legacy settings can then be removed:

```
terminal.integrated.shell.windows
terminal.integrated.shell.windowsExec
terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows
```